# Listen to firestore document changes inside a streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Flutter makes it very easy to listen live to document changes through the `StreamBuilder` widget. I am trying to count how often a document is downloaded onto the client but I can't do that when I am using a `StreamBuilder` since it doesn't offer this functionality. I tried cheating by increasing a counter on the build function but as long as something on the screen changes, it will increase the counter, even if there are no document changes.

Is there a way to count the downloads of documents?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a guess... can you achieve this through Firebase's Cloud Functions?

Comment: I don't get what you want to count exactly. Do you want to count the number of api call for a specific document globally or locally?

Comment: @MatthewTrent yes, it is possible, but it would be very overkill, to track reads by increasing a counter using a write. I would like to to it on the client-side.

Comment: @CrimsonFoot I'd like to count the number of document read operations, whenever a document is downloaded. A `StreamBuilder` reads changes which also count as read operations. This way, I am hoping to track the usage per `group`, `tag`, or whatever entity I am associating this with. In other words, I'd like to make some calculations for certain costs.

Comment: @Albert It seems that you want some analytics. Why don't you refer to this documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs

Comment: @CrimsonFoot as I mentioned in my post and my comments above, I'd like to do that client-side and not per cloud function.

Comment: @Albert So you want to do that task on client-side including the case other clients fetch the document?

Comment: @CrimsonFoot as the title and tags suggest, Client-Side using Flutter

Comment: So let's make it clear. You have client-1, client-2
1. Client-1 opens the app and listens to any reads on one document .
2. if Client-2 gets a document then client-1 will be notified that the document was got by someone. (But this will happen only when a client-1 is currently using your app and has a connection to the Internet, and also in the page where you use the stream builder widget).

Comment: Can you show your code that we can see the way you applied your logic, Please share your code as well to get better answer.

Comment: @Diwyansh this question applies to every implementation of the standard `StreamBuilder` with a `FirebaseFirestore` stream. I do not have a concrete example because I have not started a project or will start a project if this functionality is not possible.

Comment: @HamdamMuqimov Imagine the Flutter Demo-app with the counter where it increases when a document has changed and the change is downloaded onto the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether it is possible to be accurate in counting the usage of the Firestore APIs. But you can hide your snapshot stream behind a `BehaviorSubject` from `rxdart`, so that on rebuilding of `StreamBuilders` the value stored by the `BehaviorSubject` is used, without touching the `snapshot`. Then you can use the method `doOnData` on the `snapshot`.

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _firestoreSnapshots =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("myCollection")
          .snapshots()
          .doOnData((event) {
    print(event);
});


/// Wrapper around the Firestore snapshot, to be able to
/// remember the latest value and subscribe multiple times.
BehaviorSubject<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
      behaviorFirestoreCollection = BehaviorSubject();

FirestoreRepository() {
    // Expose the snapshot on the behavior subject
    behaviorFirestoreCollection.addStream(_firestoreSnapshots);
}
```

Your `StreamBuilder` will subscribe to the behaviour subject. On rebuild of the `StreamBuilder` (for reasons other than a new emitted value), the `print` will not happen.

Whether this would work without the behaviour subject, I am not sure. You could try that first.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Flutter says that `snapshots()` doesn't have the `doOnData` method :/

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have mentioned that you get that method from the `rxdart` package. It is an `extension` on `Stream` given by the package.

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing this. Could you provide some sort of example implementation?

Comment: If you share your attempt on GitHub I can have a look and do a PR.